# char array in c not working with visual studio 2015

Tags: c

1. Is this the only way to pick up a string? Can not you take character by character into an array?
2. I get an error accessing memory. The code and the error are attached.

```
void main()
{
    int counA = 0, countB = 0, Na, Nc, i, index;
    printf("enter Na and Nc\n");
    scanf_s("%d%d", &Na, &Nc);
    char DNA[1000], SEQ[1000], str[1000];

    printf("enter mulekula\n");
    scanf_s("%s", str);
}
```

input:

```
2
3
AAA
```

message I get:

```
exception thrown...
```

Comment: Post the code as text.

Comment: Paste code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Where is your code? There isn't even a picture of your code. Paste your code into the question and take 2-3 minutes and learn how to format questions properly. It's really easy. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: There is still no code. We cannot read your mind. Please [edit] your question and put your code _into your question_.

Comment: You are using `scanf_s` with `%s` specifier incorrectly. *"Unlike `scanf` ... `scanf_s` ... requires the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable."* The compiler should be issuing a warning about this.

Comment: You're doing it wrong, read carefully the documentation of [`scanf_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l), or just use `scanf` (without the `_s`) and ignore the Microsoft warnings.

Comment: "Is this the only way to pick up a string?" No, you can use `fgets()` but you need to [remove any trailing newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221).

Comment: @Jabberwocky it is better to `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` rather than hunt though warnings for relevant ones.

Comment: I added the current line you said:
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
And still requires me to use: s_scanf ()

Comment: It must be *before* the `#include` files.I also `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` and `#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE`.

Comment: i added and still i get this message error:                                                 
                                                                                                                 
Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error C4996 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. Project5 c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\project5\project5\dna.c 22

Comment: It must be ***before*** the `#include` files. But having reverted to `scanf` you must still restrict the input length with `scanf("%999s", str);` It's true that the function is unsafe, but no function is safe when used incorrectly, including MS's allegedly "safe" (and non-portable) version".

Comment: It works!!!
Thank you.
But I still did not understand why I could not pick up characters in the following way?char DNA[1000];
 for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
 {

  scanf("%c", &DNA[i]);

 }

Comment: Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer).

Answer (score 0):

fgets can help , see this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
chat str[1000];

fegts(str,sizeof(str),stdin);

str[strlen(str)-1]='\0';
return 0;

}
```

This code will take input from console till you press enter , but take care that fgets includes the new line character('\n') with input so we need to remove it and end the string with null character ('\0') .

This is the reason for this line of code `str[strlen(str)-1]='\0';` so strlen(str) will return the length of string including new line character.

### for example :

### if input was **"fo"** , so it stored in str as follow:

str[0] = 'f' , str[1]='o' , str[2]='\n' and str[3]='\0'.
So **strlen(str)-1** will return 2 , so str[2] will be assigned to null character '\0'

### And finally the string will be as follow:

str[0] = 'f' , str[1]='o' and str[2]='\0'.